# How to create a graph object in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I'd like to use the NetLogo's R extension to send a graph object into R, then use the iGraph package to calculate and return some metrics. iGraph can create a graph from an adjacency matrix or an edgelist (there are other options too). The graph I'd like to send to R is just the links among an agentset. Does anyone know how to do this? The NW:save-matrix will export an adjacency matrix to a file. Do I need to do this and then read the file back into R or is there a more direct way?

As always, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done in the past is construct the network within NetLogo, export the network to R, calculate the network metrics in R, and then retrieve the metrics. The relevant code I used in one of those projects is:

```
to export-nw2r
  ; create file with useful graph format
  nw:set-context people links
  let filename (word "Networks/netlogo" behaviorspace-run-number ".gml")
  export-simple-gml filename

  ;; reset the R-workspace
  r:clearLocal
  let dir pathdir:get-model
  r:eval "library(igraph)"

  ; read network in R
  set filename (word dir "/" filename)
  r:put "fn" filename
  r:eval "gg <- read_graph(file = fn, format = 'gml')"
  r:eval "V(gg)$name <- V(gg)$id"          ; gml uses 'id', but igraph uses 'name'
  r:eval "if (file.exists(fn)) file.remove(fn)"
end

to calc-network-properties
  r:eval "library(ineq)"

  ; network size
  set sizeN count people
  set sizeE count links
  output-type "Nodes: " output-print sizeN
  output-type "Edges: " output-print sizeE

  ; calculate degree properties
  r:eval "degs <- degree(gg)"
  r:eval "aveDeg <- mean(degs)"
  set aveDeg r:get "aveDeg"
  output-type "Mean Degree: " output-print precision aveDeg 2
  r:eval "giniDeg <- ineq(degs, type = \"Gini\")"
  set giniDeg r:get "giniDeg"
  output-type "Gini of Degree: " output-print precision giniDeg 2

  ; calculate transitivity properties
  r:eval "lccs <- transitivity(gg, type = \"localundirected\")"
  r:eval "aveCC <- mean(lccs, na.rm = TRUE)"
  set aveCC r:get "aveCC"
  output-type "Mean Clustering: " output-print precision aveCC 2
  r:eval "trans <- transitivity(gg, type = \"undirected\")"
  set trans r:get "trans"
  output-type "Transitivity: " output-print precision trans 2

  ; paths and betweenness
  r:eval "paths <- distances(gg)"
  r:eval "paths <- paths[upper.tri(paths)]"
  r:eval "avePath <- mean(paths)"
  set avePath r:get "avePath"
  output-type "Mean Shortest Path: " output-print precision avePath 2
  r:eval "diam <- max(paths)"
  set diam r:get "diam"
  output-type "Max Shortest Path: " output-print diam
  r:eval "giniPaths <- ineq(paths, type = \"Gini\")"
  set giniPaths r:get "giniPaths"
  output-type "Gini of Paths: " output-print precision giniPaths 2
  r:eval "btws <- betweenness(gg)"
  r:eval "giniBtwn <- ineq(btws, type = \"Gini\")"
  set giniBtwn r:get "giniBtwn"
  output-type "Gini of Betweenness (V): " output-print precision giniBtwn 2
end
```